# How do you defer setCss?

Tags: javascript, css

I load an iframe from third party source.

```
<iframe src="https://thirdparty.com/"></iframe>
```

In footer, I reference the JS script:

```
<script src="https://thirdparty.com/src.js"></script>
```

And I apply CSS styles also in footer. This is how third party says to load custom styles:

```
<script>thirdparty.setCss('https://example.com/site.css')</script>
```

To improve performance, I want to defer JS script. If I add `defer` to script

```
<script defer src="https://thirdparty.com/src.js"></script>
```

I get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: thirdparty is not defined. I think this is because CSS file loads before JS file.

How do I defer load of CSS file also as adding defer to CSS script does not work?

Comment: A CSS stylesheet file has nothing to do with any JS script and cannot possibly know if it's existence, it is 100% safe to load the CSS whenever you wish without any error thrown.

Comment: Most likely, "https://thirdparty.com/src.js" contains the source for the "thirdparty.setCss()" function. Put that line in an external file and add a  `<script defer src="externalFile.js"></script>` line after the one referencing "src.js".

Comment: You have this error because some other script was dependent on thiat third-party script which you have deferred, therefore it expected something to exist. You need to check which script is using this third-party script and understand the relationship of them. They *must* be loaded in **synchronized order**.

Comment: Get the `loadscript` function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/3684265, then use this code: `loadScript('https://thirdparty.com/src.js', function(){        
        thirdparty.setCss('https://example.com/site.css')
    })` It will load the javascript file dynamically then onload it will use the setCSS within the call back function